# hardhat-deploy openzeppelin transparent proxies

Tags: hardhat, proxy-contracts, hardhat-deploy

Could anyone please share how can we use `hardhat-deploy` with openzeppelin transparent proxies properly because the `hardhat-deploy` seems to have this option but I was not able to find any good reference to use them both like proper workflow how it's done. Even a link to a repo that has been implemented will help a lot. Thanks

Comment: Even I referred to their docs: https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#deploying-and-upgrading-proxies But was not able to understand correctly.
please let me know, if you found something helpful in regard to this.
Thanks!